# Flashing LG G4 H815(International Version) rom onto LG G4 H812 (Bell Canada) hardware

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, unbricking, compatibility, lg-g4

I am going on a long trip to the UK and Middle East, and want to take my LG G4 with me and use foreign service providers. I am planning on flashing the H815T (Similar to H815 International Version but supports more bands) KDZ file onto my existing LG H812 (Bell Canada) hardware, so I can have support for those frequency bands in the UK and Middle East.

According to my understanding, the H815T rom is compatible with the H812 hardware, as both the Bell Canada and International Versions have the same underlying hardware, but I would gladly appreciate if someone can confirm this. I have attached the phone details below.

Thanks and all the best!

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "According to my understanding, the H815T rom is compatible with the H812 hardware" - how do you know?

Comment: They have the exact same hardware: CPU, GPU, chipset, instruction set, RAM, etc

Comment: And so what? All G4 variants share those, yet you see them configured and locked to certain network types. Baseband hardware is just different. Also, good luck flashing anything for non-T-Mobile or non-European LG phones, they are heavily locked down.

Comment: The H915T is the international version not T-mobile. I checked the supported bands, the H812 is a direct subset of those supported by H815T

Comment: What I mean is, presumably you won't be able to flash anything on a phone that's *not* from Europe (H815) or T-Mobile (H811) because of their locked bootloader. Also, H812's bands being a direct *subset* of H815T likely means that the hardware (e.g. antenna, as Sean pointed out below) isn't prepared for the extra bands.

Comment: Hi Andy, you bring up a valid point, saying the GSM frequency bands are hardware based. That could very well be a possibility. But if that were the case, then howcome when you unlock the phone, it suddenly supports all the frequency bands? This leads me to believe bands are purely software based.

Answer (score 0):

one thought and I don't know for sure but it's ok if the ROMs say they support those freqs but does the internal antenna support those freqs as well  being that it's a T-Mobile phone

Comment: If the supported frequency bands are hardware based,, then howcome when you unlock the phone, it suddenly supports all the frequency bands? This leads me to believe bands are purely software based.